# Avoiding using parseInt/Float when getting element.value

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, types, integer

I have a table in HTML where I am getting the row ID from , putting it into an array in JavaScript and then trying to do work on the rows. Think of it like an excel sheet that only accepts number inputs, I have already checked for just number inputs and I want to assign the value for each cell as a float at the start of my code, so I don't have to write parseFloat() every single time I want to do some maths on a cell. I only care about rows that contain input in cell 2 so the last bit of the code just removes these.

```js
var table = [];
    
//Get the row information and store it in the table by row AND MAKE THEM NUMBERS
    

for(let i =0; i<10; i+=1){
    table.push(document.getElementsByName("row"+(i+1)));
    //set no entries to 0 or their number
    for(let k=0; k<3; k+=1){
        if(table[i][k].value =="" || table[i][k].value ==0 || table[i][k].value == NaN || table[i][k].value == undefined){
            table[i][k].value = 0;
        }
        else{
            table[i][k].value = parseFloat(table[i][k].value);
        }
    }
    if(parseFloat(table[i][1].value) == NaN || parseFloat(table[i][1].value) == 0){
        //remove the 0 values from the last row
        table[i][0].value ="";
        table[i][1].value ="";
        table[i][2].value ="";
        //remove the row from table
        table.pop();
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Table data start -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row1" ></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row2"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row2"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row2"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row2"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row3"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row3"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row3"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row3"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row4"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row4"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row4"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row4"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row5"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row5"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row5"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row5"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row6"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row6"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row6"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row6"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row7"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row7"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row7"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row7"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row8"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row8"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row8"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row8"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row8"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row9"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row9"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row9"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row9"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row9"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row10"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row10"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row10"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row10"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row10"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" id="submit">
<input type="reset">
```

I want to set the `table[row][cell].value` to a number from it's original HTML string and store that so I can directly do something like:

`table[row][cell].value += 100;`

With out it concatenating the string. I am hundreds of lines in and adding parse to nearly every line is bloating my code and trying to find every time I'd forgotten to add it was a nightmare.

Comment: could you provide some working code with HTML here it a snippet? so it would be easier to comprehend your problem

Comment: Added HTML for you, I basically want the data to be converted to a float in the array while the code runs, then I don't mind if if it's converted back to a string after it finishes. This way I can work with the data. A thought I had was to make a copy of the table with float values and Boolean for the check boxes  and use that as a working copy, if there's no other way to do it.

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run.  However it doesn't really do anything. I assume you want that JS to run when the "Submit" button is pressed instead of when the page is loaded?

Comment: Yeah I do, I left that bit out, sorry. Mainly my question is about working with values from the table array, I want to convert the elements value into a float from a string and store that float in the table instead

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to do with your last row, your logic is misleading, but for number values use `HTMLInputElement::valueAsNumber`:

```js
const $table = document.querySelector('table');
$table.addEventListener('input', tweakInputs);
tweakInputs();

function tweakInputs(){

  const table = [];

  //Get the row information and store it in the table by row AND MAKE THEM NUMBERS
  
  $table.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach($row => {
  

    const inputs = $row.querySelectorAll('[type=number]');
    table.push(inputs);
    
    inputs.forEach(input => input.value = input.valueAsNumber || 0);
        
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- Table data start -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row1" ></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row2"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row2"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row2"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row2"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row3"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row3"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row3"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row3"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row4"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row4"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row4"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row4"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row5"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row5"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row5"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row5"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row6"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row6"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row6"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row6"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row7"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row7"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row7"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row7"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row8"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row8"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row8"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row8"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row8"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row9"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row9"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row9"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row9"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row9"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row10"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row10"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="fitToDiv" name="row10"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row10"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="fitToDiv" name="row10"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" id="submit">
<input type="reset">
```